# Xamarin my app crashes on boot when it is invisible

Tags: android, xamarin

I can hide my app with this code;

```
PackageManager p = PackageManager;
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, Class);
            p.SetComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
            ComponentEnabledState.Disabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);
```

but my application on boot stopping to work when it is invisible with above codes. My app runs on boot without errors when it is visible.

How can I run my app on boot as invisible without crash errors?

Comment: Where did you call these codes when your app is invisible ?

Comment: @Leo Zhu - MSFT    MainActivity.cs

Comment: In the `OnStop` method of MainActivity ?

Comment: @Leo Zhu - MSFT   no, in OnCreate method of MainActivity.And I call MainAcitivity from my foreground service to seeing error and it is giving me error: "Unable to find explicit activity class"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making my app visible in BroadCastReceiver class. My application then becomes invisible again in the MainActivity class.

My broadcastreceiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, DirectBootAware = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public ContextWrapper context_;
    public async override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PackageManager p = context_.PackageManager;
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context,
        Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)).Name);
        p.SetComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
        ComponentEnabledState.Enabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);

        await Task.Delay(8000);
        Intent start = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        start.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        context.StartActivity(start);
        
    }
}
```